# Type for a function that receives an array and returns a single element of that array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

I have this function that should return a random item of an array.

```
function getRandomArrayItem {
  return arr[Math.floor((Math.random()*arr.length))];
}
```

I'm gonna use it as follows:

```
const LANGUAGE_VALUES = ["EN","ES"] as const;

// I HAVE THIS TYPE
type LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE = typeof LANGUAGE_VALUES[number];   // THIS IS: "EN" | "ES"

// I NEED TO CALL getRandomArrayItem ON LANGUAGE_VALUES TO SELECTED A RANDOM LANGUAGE:

const language = getRandomArrayItem(LANGUAGE_VALUES);
```

I need the randomly selected language to be of the type `LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE`. I.E: `"EN" | "ES"`.

How can I do that?

Also, I would like it to be generic, cause I'll be using that function in other similar arrays, but with different content.

Comment: In your example `LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE` would be of type string, not `'EN' | 'ES'`, because `LANGUAGE_VALUES` is infered as `string[]`

Comment: @gbalduzzi  Sorry, I forgot to add the `const assertion`. Will add that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generics and typescript inference:

```
function getRandomArrayItem<T>(arr: T[]): T {
   return arr[Math.floor((Math.random()*arr.length))];
}

const language = getRandomArrayItem(LANGUAGE_VALUES); // Language is now type of the content of LANGUAGE_VALUES array
```

In your example it is a bit trickier to cast `LANGUAGE_VALUES` to the proper type. You need to first define the language type and then define the actual array, such as:

```
const VALUES_CONST = ["EN","ES"] as const;
type LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE = typeof VALUES_CONST[number];

const LANGUAGE_VALUES: LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE[] = ["EN","ES"]

const result = getRandomArrayItem<LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE>(LANGUAGE_VALUES)

// Result is of type 'EN' | 'ES'
```

Or force the casting:

```js
const LANGUAGE_VALUES = ["EN","ES"] as const;
type LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE = typeof LANGUAGE_VALUES[number];   // THIS IS: "EN" | "ES"


const language = getRandomArrayItem(LANGUAGE_VALUES as unknown as LANGUAGE_VALUES_TYPE[]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `Cannot find name T`. Don't I need the type parameter `<T>` as in `getRandomArrayItem<T>(arr: T[]): T` ?

Comment: Uhm my fault, I forgot to add it

Comment: It still does not work. I'm getting `Argument of type 'readonly ["EN", "ES"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'unknown[]'.
  The type 'readonly ["EN", "ES"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'unknown[]'.`

Comment: I think your answer might work, if `LANGUAGE_VALUES` wasn't being declared are `as const`. I might need to refactor some stuff to make it work.

Comment: Yeah I'm just tinkering with it in the playground. Using `as const` it is not anymore an array of `'EN' | 'ES'` but it is _exactly_ ['en', 'es'], so  it can't be cast to the generic `T[]`.

Comment: Thanks. I really need to do some refactoring, because `LANGUAGE_VALUES` is what is being used to generate the union type. So I cannot used the union type to set the type on it, because I get a circular reference. You've worked around that but now we are declaring the same array twice. Your answer is correct, though. Thanks again.